# При обращении к статичному классу выскакивает noclassdeffounderror

Tags: java, android

Я создаю БД и в статическом классе держу названия полей и типов полей. При создании первых двух таблиц никаких проблем не происходит, но почему то при создании следующих таблиц выскакивает данная ошибка.

код статичного класса:

```
public static abstract class FirmsEntry implements BaseColumns{

    public static final int IS_ON_INDEX = 0;
    public static final int IS_OFF_INDEX = 1;
    public static final String COLUMN_FIRM_ID = "firm_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "firm_name";
    public static final String COLUMN_DESCR = "firm_descr";
    public static final String COLUMN_RATING = "firm_rating";
    public static final String COLUMN_IS_ON = "firm_is_on";

    public static final String[] COLUMNS = new String[] { _ID, COLUMN_FIRM_ID, 
         COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_DESCR, COLUMN_RATING, COLUMN_IS_ON};
    public static final String[] TYPES = new String[] { TYPE_PRIMARY_KEY, 
         TYPE_TEXT, TYPE_TEXT, TYPE_TEXT, TYPE_TEXT, TYPE_INT};
}
```

Обращение к нему:

```
db.execSQL(createTable(UserContract.TABLE_NAME_FIRMS, 
     FirmsEntry.COLUMNS, FirmsEntry.TYPES));
```

Метод createTable:

```
private String createTable(String tableName, String[] columns, String[] types) {
    if (tableName == null || columns == null || types == null
            || types.length != columns.length || types.length == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Invalid parameters for creating table " + tableName);
    } else {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("CREATE TABLE ");

        stringBuilder.append(tableName);
        stringBuilder.append(" (");
        for (int n = 0, i = columns.length; n < i; n++) {
            if (n > 0) {
                stringBuilder.append(", ");
            }
            stringBuilder.append(columns[n]).append(' ')
                    .append(types[n]);
        }
        return stringBuilder.append(");").toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Статический класс внутри другого класса лежит? или в отдельном файле? Если все-таки вдруг второе, то наверно стоит убрать `static` в определении класса, т.к "Объявить статическим также можно и класс, за исключением классов **верхнего уровня**. Такие классы известны как «вложенные статические классы» (`nested static class`).

Comment: @I.Smirnov внутри другого класса